# How to arrange arrays in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of personal data(id_code,birth_year,born_in) and i want to sort the any arrays in list but i have a problem in this work.

my list data :

```
data = [
    'id_code:3211238576;birth_year:1350;born_in:Boushehr',
    'id_code:9801233575;born_in:Argentina;birth_year:1360',
    'born_in:Portugal;id_code:0219206431;birth_year:1358',
    'id_code:0021678913;born_in:Shiraz;birth_year:1120',
    'id_code:1101102135;born_in:Gilan;birth_year:1152',

]
```

The code I wrote and has an bug:

```
for i in data:
    s = ''.join(sorted(i))
    print(s)
```

my code output:

```
01112233355678:::;;B___abbcddeeehhhiiinnooorrrrstuy
00112333556789:::;;A___aabbcddeeeghiiiinnnnoorrrrtty
00111223345689:::;;P___aabbcddeeghiiilnnooorrrrttuy
00011112236789:::;;S___aabbcddeehhiiiinnoorrrrtyz
00111111122355:::;;G___aabbcddeehiiiilnnnoorrrty
```

But! The code to i want to have in output(True answer):

```
id_code:3211238576,born_in:Boushehr,birth_year:1350
id_code:9801233575,born_in:Argentina,birth_year:1360
id_code:0219206431,born_in:Portugal,birth_year:1358
id_code:0021678913,born_in:Shiraz,birth_year:1120
id_code:1101102135,born_in:Gilan,birth_year:1152
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: The problem is that you're calling `sorted` on each of your strings, and it's then printing the characters of each of those strings in alphabetical order.

Comment: please put your answer in answer part

Comment: What "arrays"? What field are you trying to sort on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```py
out = [';'.join(reversed(sorted(x.split(';')))) for x in data]
print(out)
```

This takes every element of the `data` list and splits it in three strings, each of which contains one of the three attributes. Then, it arranges  the three strings in reversed alphabetical order and joins them back into one string, separated by ';'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want your fields to be in specific order, try this one: (I put comments in code for clarification):

```
data = [
    'id_code:3211238576;birth_year:1350;born_in:Boushehr',
    'id_code:9801233575;born_in:Argentina;birth_year:1360',
    'born_in:Portugal;id_code:0219206431;birth_year:1358',
    'id_code:0021678913;born_in:Shiraz;birth_year:1120',
    'id_code:1101102135;born_in:Gilan;birth_year:1152',
]


def sorter(x: str):
    # getting the field name
    field = x.split(':')[0]
    
    # returning it's index from "sorted_by" list
    return sorted_by.index(field)


# The index of these fields will be used for sorting in "sorter" function.
sorted_by = ['id_code', 'born_in', 'birth_year']

result = []
for item in data:
    
    # splitting the fields
    splited = item.split(';')
    
    splited.sort(key=sorter)
    
    # building the line back and append it
    result.append(';'.join(splited))

for i in result:
    print(i)
```

output :

```
id_code:3211238576;born_in:Boushehr;birth_year:1350
id_code:9801233575;born_in:Argentina;birth_year:1360
id_code:0219206431;born_in:Portugal;birth_year:1358
id_code:0021678913;born_in:Shiraz;birth_year:1120
id_code:1101102135;born_in:Gilan;birth_year:1152
```

Now you can easily change the fields order in `sorted_by` list and see the result.